# Program doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't get why the part `not_com_word` doesn't print the guessed characters together.
Now in each loop in the guess function the `not_com_word` that stands for not completed word must show the guessed characters together and the left hidden characters.

```
# Country Guess game produced by Farzad YZ
import random
import string
print '**Guessing game [Country version]---Powered by Farzad YZ**'
seq = ['iran','iraq','england','germany','france','usa','uruguay','pakistan']
choice = random.choice(seq)
length = len(choice)
print 'The hidden word is:',length*'*'
def guess():
    while 1:
        not_com_word = ''
        i = raw_input('Guess the character in turn: ')
        if i == choice[g]:
            print 'That is right!'
            not_com_word = not_com_word + i
            print 'Guessed till here ->',not_com_word,((length-g-1)*'*')
            break
        else:
            print 'Wrong! Try again.'
            continue

g = 0
while g < length:
    guess()
    if g == length-1:
        print '''Congratulations! You guessed the country finally.
The country was %s.''' %choice
    g = g+1
```

Comment: The wrong part is where you have this all in one code block, instead of having it broken down into a number of functions (like a `generateHiddenWord`, `promptUserForInput`, etc.)

Comment: Harsh. It's not that bad.

Comment: i know but in this notation its still working.
The only part thats not working correctly is the variable not_com_word :(

Comment: It's spelled "uruguay"

Comment: Where is `g` initialized in `guess()`? I would pass that as a variable to the `guess` function. That, or use the `global` flag.

Comment: make sure you need g variable, as local or global.

Comment: @luminous: it's bad style, but the function can read the global `g` without a `global` keyword because that's not what the `global` keyword does.

Comment: Thanks to all.
i found out variable not_com_word must be defined as global var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time guess gets called the var not_com_word gets set to ''.
To fix it, move it outside of the function and make it accessible with global.

```
....    
not_com_word = ''

def guess():
    global not_com_word
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Here another sample implementation, without the need to use global variables:

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

import random

countries = ['iran','iraq','england','germany','france','usa','uruguay','pakistan']

def guess(country):
    guessed = ''
    print 'The hidden word is:', len(country) * '*'
    while country:
        c = raw_input('Guess the character in turn: ')
        if c == country[0]:
            guessed += c
            country = country[1:]
            print 'That is right!'
            print 'Guessed until now:', guessed + len(country) * '*'
            continue
        print 'Wrong! Try again.'
    print 'You guessed', guessed

guess(random.choice(countries))
```